# Governor Limit on number of child records fetched

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

A SOQL query can return a maximum of 50,000 records, is there any limit on the number of child records that can be fetched in a SOQL query.

Example, I have an Account name as 'DBZ' having more than 50,000 contacts. So will below query can hit any governor limit ?

```
List<Account> acc_Contacts = [Select name, (Select id, name from Contacts) from Account where name = 'DBZ']
```

Since i am having a developer edition org, i cant check it myself for this amount of data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it will because the 50,000 record count in single transaction.

As per [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm):

> In a SOQL query with parent-child relationship subqueries, each
>   parent-child relationship counts as an extra query. These types of
>   queries have a limit of three times the number for top-level queries.
>   The row counts from these relationship queries contribute to the row
>   counts of the overall code execution.

Comment: So for a given record i can fetch a max of 49999 child rows records, since 1 row will be for parent record itself. Please throw some light !!

Comment: @s_saiyan yes you are correct here.