# Exporting 10k records using visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a vf page to export records in excel format and showing parent and child records in same row.
I'm aware that Vf has a limit of exporting 10000 records.

So in  `select id,(select id,name from contact) from account` query, if account has 10 rows and each account has 2 contacts, will total rows be counted as 10 or 30.? if 30, is there a way to check both child and parent records count.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to sidestep the problem is by [Setting Read-Only Mode for an Entire Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_readonly_context_pagelevel.htm):

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" readOnly="true">
```

which:

> Normally, queries for a single Visualforce page request may not
>   retrieve more than 50,000 rows. In read-only mode, this limit is
>   relaxed to allow querying up to 1,000,000 rows.
>
> In addition to querying many more rows, the readOnly attribute also
>   increases the maximum number of items in a collection that can be
>   iterated over using components such as `<apex:dataTable>`,
>   `<apex:dataList>`, and `<apex:repeat>`. This limit increased from 1,000
>   items to 10,000.

On the record row counts, see [Governor Limit on number of child records fetched](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131866/governor-limit-on-number-of-child-records-fetched); for your example the row count will be 30.

You can check row count consumed and what the limit is at any point in your code via the [Limits Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) methods `getQueryRows` and `getLimitQueryRows`.